# Working principle between 'for' and 'while' loops in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written this code to print the names in the list 'magicians'.

```
def show_magicians(mag_names):
    print("Here is the name of the magicians")
    print("The old list is :", mag_names)
    while mag_names:
        full_name = mag_names.pop()
        printed_list.append(full_name.title())
        print("The name of the magician is ", full_name.title())
    print("The old list now :", mag_names)
    print("The new list is :", printed_list)

magicians = ['houdini', 'williams', 'sunderland']
printed_list = []

show_magicians(magicians)
```

My for loop code

```
for magician in mag_names:
     full_name = mag_names.pop()
     printed_list.append(full_name.title())
```

If I execute with `while` loop the code works fine with every name printed but with `for` loop the first element of the list is not printed as intended.

Comment: Can you show your for loop implementation as well?

Comment: Yes. Can you show code with for loop.?

Comment: Using a `while` loop for this task looks perfectly reasonable to me.  So why do you want to use a `for` loop?

Comment: @rajdeepmukherjee where is the for loop in your code? Can you show it?

Comment: Here is the code changed "for" :

for magician in mag_names:
          full_name = mag_names.pop()
          printed_list.append(full_name.title())

Comment: @rajdeepmukherjee please add it in your code

Comment: I'm not surprised that it didn't work, why did you want to use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2):

The way you wrote the for loop is the problem. As for loop takes one element from the list and passes that value inside the block and repeats the same for the next element.

`for magician in mag_names:`

here magician has one value from the start of the mag_names, in your case it is 'houdini' You shouldn't pop the mag_names inside your for loop again. So the correct code for 'for' loop will be like this

`for magician in mag_names:
    full_name = magician
    printed_list.append(full_name.title())`

Your implementation of the while loop works fine because while works differently. It executes the block as long as the condition is true. So the 
`while mag_names:` will evaluate to `True` until the items are empty. And as they are being popped out one by one in your code the list shrinks and eventually reaches empty and evaluates to `False`

And the reason why for loop and while loop implementation outputs are reversed should be obvious to you now.

Comment: thanks for the comment, In that case we can directly use the variable "magician" instead using another variable (e.g. full-name) to make more compact code writing. The reason for popping was to clear the old list and fill the new list.

Comment: Yea you can use variables directly. And to modify the list which the for loop is currently using will cause few problems. So it's best to leave the list until the loop terminates and then you use `del list_name` to remove it from memory.

Comment: And if you are concerned about memory you can try to learn about generators that yield one value, only when you request them. And mind marking it as answer if this helped ? :)

Answer (score 1):

`while` loop does not keep track of the indexes itself as does the `for` loop.

`while loop` : It just checks that `mag_names` is non-empty and it will continue to loop over. Your list becomes empty at one point of time due to popping of elements. And thus you end up the loop. While loop does not iterate to the next element on its own.

`for loop` : For loop increments to next element in each of its iteration. In your case you are also popping the element in each element thus list size reduces by 2 in each iteration, thus you dont get the same result as in while loop

The problem with your code is you are using the same list for iteration and for popping the elements. Thus in each iteration the index advances by 1 and at the same time last element is popped out.

The solution would be to use a fresh copy of `mag_names` in the iteration process by `[:]`

```
def show_magicians(mag_names):
      print("Here is the name of the magicians")
      print("The old list is :", mag_names)
      for magician in mag_names[:]:
          full_name = mag_names.pop() 
          printed_list.append(full_name.title())
          print("The name of the magician is ", full_name.title())
      print("The old list now :", mag_names)
      print("The new list is :", printed_list)

magicians = ['houdini', 'williams', 'sunderland']
printed_list = []
show_magicians(magicians)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead writing a complex bit of code, let's make it simple by using `append` and then using `printed_list[:] = []` to empty the list. Here is the code:

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
    print("Here is the name of the magicians")
    print("The old list is :",magicians)
    while magicians:
        full_name = magicians.pop()
        printed_list.append(full_name.title())
        print("The name of the magician is ",full_name.title())
    print("The old list now :",magicians)
    print("The new list is :",printed_list)
    print("***********With for loop******************")
    for magician in printed_list:
        printed_list_new.append(magician)
        print("The name of the magician is ", magician)
    printed_list[:] = []
    print("The old list now:", printed_list)
    print("The new list now:", printed_list_new)
magicians = ['houdini', 'williams', 'sunderland']
printed_list = []
printed_list_new = []
show_magicians(magicians)
```

I tweaked some pieces of your code, to make it work. Hope it helps :)